# Twig enable cache after loading Environment

Tags: php, twig

I want to enable caching in Twig.
I found how to do this during creating of a Twig Environment object

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    'cache' => '/path/to/compilation_cache',
));
```

But i want to add caching after object is constructed. Now can i do this?

I have the class that inherits Twig

```
class MyTwig extends Twig_Environment {
    public function someFunction() {
         // enable cache there
    }
}
```

I need to enable cache inside the function someFunction()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look inside Environment.php, there is a method called `setCache`. So I guess you can simply:

```
public function loadTwig() {
    // ...
    $this->twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, $params);
    // ...
}

public function someFunction() {
    // ...
    $this->twig->setCache('/path/to/compilation_cache');
    // ...
}
```